# Take user defined function without eval in AMO approved way

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm making an add-on which is kind of like gestures, but only rocker and wheel gestures on mouse. So now users can create any functions, there are some default functions I ship the add-on with. But I would like users to share.

Right now users can click on "Share" button and it posts it to my website. I want to add like a "Add" button on my pages so other users can come to the site and click it to add it. It keeps stats of most popular downloads etc.

My problem is I need to avoid `eval` as AMO doesn't like that. Any ideas how I can take user submitted code on my site and into my add-on? Right now I store the functions as strings in a preference thats formated as json. Then I `eval` the functions in there.

Answer (score 1):

Check with amo-editors about that, **before** you do any actual work. The idea sounds like it will be rejected (unless you have only a limited API).

Best would be to provide a limited API that has a scope narrow enough so that it can be reviewed/audited, and that doesn't allow to do really evil stuff (without user consent). Inject that API into an unprivileged Sandbox, et voilà (aka. what Greasemonkey does).
Even then, I wouldn't be too sure that AMO would allow it (GM/user-scripts kind of are long enough around to be considered "special").

But from your description it sounds like you would like these scripts to be able to perform anything and everything. So, basically these scripts are actual add-ons themselves (in capabilities).
At the very least you'd need install UI comparable to the general add-on install UI when installing from unprivileged sites. And I'd guess a way to let you and/or mozilla blacklist individual scripts after the fact. Let's not even start discussing update mechanisms at this point...

The central repository (your site) also seems like a single big point-of-failure.

Comment: Aw dang, ok I'll check with them. I was trying to offer this feature because add-ons like MozGestures was discontinued and it had this awesome custom function thing which I used a ton. Then FireGestures has it too but their sharing is horrible, you can't share, its up to the authors whim to update his site with scripts we can add in. Ya I need it acess to anything/everything :( Ill chek with them. Btw regarldess if they allow it, any ideas on how to go about this without an `eval`?